# FileAcceessing Media File and Permission

Tags: android

I am trying to play an MP4 video file from the Movies directory on the internal storage. The problem is it keep saying the following: This video can't be played. The same video is being played successfully from the raw directory.

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
String mediaPath = path.getAbsolutePath()+"/final_video_loop.mp4";
if(new File(mediaPath).exists()) {
    Toast toat = Toast.makeText(this, mediaPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toat.show();
}
```

The above code works which means is sees the file but can't play it.

Comment: Try also File.canRead().

Comment: The mp4 can be played with a 3rd party software on the device

Comment: Irrelevant. Try canRead() please.

Comment: I tried it the file seems to be not readable since toast did not show up

Comment: Use breakpoints to understand where's the problem, after that you should be able to solve it.

Comment: Have you requested READ permission in manifest file? And have you added code to request the user at runtime to confirm that request?

Comment: @blackapps Yes I have tried it and it did not help. Write & read alone and together

Comment: Please post your videoplayer code. Also that for playing from raw. You are not on Android Q?